# Transfer learning for regression problems?

Tags: regression, transfer-learning

How does transfer learning work for regression tasks? Can someone point to an application where transfer learning has been successfully applied for regression tasks.

Comment: Do you need it to be regression to regression transfer learning or can be from classification to regression? The latter is quite common actually.

Comment: It would be great to know about both. If you can shed some light on either/both or point me to an application/papers that would be great.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection and https://www.kaggle.com/c/aptos2019-blindness-detection is one example of classification to regression.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the denoising autoencoder. The input features to a neural network are contaminated by a small amount of noise, sent through one or more intermediate layers, and then through a final layer of the same size as the input layer. This network is optimized to reconstruct the original data which can be seen as a form of regularization.

The resulting network weights (minus the final layer) are frozen and transferred to a supervised learning task (perhaps added to another neural network). It has been found that the features constructed by this process are quite valuable. This applies to regression or classification.

Comment: Could you add some references/links/examples to this answer?